# React.js bundle size too big when using router and browserify

Tags: node.js, reactjs, browserify, react-router, babeljs

This is my Routes.jsx file

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router/lib/router')
var useRouterHistory = require('react-router/lib/useRouterHistory');
var hashHistory = require('history/lib/createHashHistory');
var IndexRoute = require('react-router/lib/IndexRoute');

var Route = require('react-router/lib/Route');

var History = useRouterHistory(hashHistory)({
    queryKey: false
});

var Base = require('./components/Pages/Base.jsx');
var HomePage = require('./components/Pages/HomePage.jsx');
var Historial = require('./components/Pages/Historial.jsx');
var NuevoPedido = require('./components/Pages/NuevoPedido.jsx');

var Routes  = (
    <Router history={History}>
        <Route path="/" component={Base}>
            <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
            <Route path="/historial" component={Historial} />
            <Route path="/pedido/nuevo" component={NuevoPedido} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
);

module.exports = Routes;
```

My compile script looks like this

```
watchify src/main.jsx -v -t [ babelify --presets [ react es2015 ] ]  -o public/js/main.js
```

This outputs a file that's 1532 KB

And my production script looks like this

```
SET NODE_ENV=production & browserify src/main.jsx -v -t [ babelify --presets [ react es2015 ] ] -g [uglifyify] -o public/js/bundle.js
```

This outputs a file that's 730 KB

I have the following dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "desandro-classie": "^1.0.1",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0",
    "reflux": "^0.3.0",
    "validator": "^5.0.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^0.11.0"
  },
```

Even uglified and compressed the file size is 730 kb which is huge for the little code i have written.

I noticed that if a take out EG:

```
var NuevoPedido = require('./components/Pages/NuevoPedido.jsx');
Which is a "page wrapper"
```

and it's corresponding route

```
<Route path="/pedido/nuevo" component={NuevoPedido} />
```

Removing any route and it's component cut's down like 500 kb from the 1.5 mb file, but that's crazy because those components are not any near to be 500kb, so i suspect that there has to be some kind of dependencies duplication, i tried npm dedupe with no luck.

You can check my github rep https://github.com/Mercality/dilugaReact to verify this.